# A Change of Variable/Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

A line in a text reads $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mu (B(x,u^{\frac{-1}{t}}) du = t\int_{0}^{\infty} r^{-t-1} \mu (B(x,r)) dr.$$

I set $u=r^{-t}$. But then $du=-tr^{-t-1} dr$. Where is the negative?

Comment: should the $-1/t$ on the LHS be $-t$? Also remember than when dealing with the Lebesgue integral the factor in the change of variables formula is the absolute value of the Jacobian of the transformation (if not, the integral should be taken from $\infty$ to $0$, and inverting the order spits out the missing minus sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the change of variable, you obtain

$$\int_{\infty}^0 -tr^{-t-1} \mu(B(x,r)) dr$$

So if you want an integral between $0$ and $\infty$, the minus sign disapear